# How does bash retrieves what was written on the terminal (without Enter being pressed)?

Tags: bash, terminal, tty, input

Say that the `ping` command is running, and I type something on the terminal while `ping` is still running.

Now when `ping` terminates and `bash` gain back control, `bash` will print on the terminal what I typed while `ping` was running. This is a screenshot that shows what I mean:

[image]

How did `bash` get this information? I am sure it did not get it from `stdin`, because when I typed `"I typed this while ping was running"`, I did not press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (and so `stdin` is empty).

Comment: Where do you expect the keys strokes you are entering while ping is running are going?  If ping is not consuming them, they are queued.  When ping is done, they are waiting  and in this case bash gets them....

Comment: Although Unix tty drivers conventionally don't deliver input (as opposed to signals) until you type EOL (usually CR/Enter) or EOF (usually control-D), they can be set to 'raw' mode which does not wait, and bash normally does this in order to support command line editing and completion; see the (rather large) section with that title in the bash manual/info.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch In what queue the key strokes are stored? If I am writing a program in `C` that executes `ping`, and so when `ping` terminates, my program gain back control, what function should I call to get what was typed while `ping` was running (to get data from this queue)?

Comment: Additional Information. If line editing disabled, then behavior is changing. To turn off line editing: either run the subshell `bash --noediting` or `set +o emacs` in the current shell. I have discovered following: typed characters don't appear in the end, but you can remove part of prompt string by quantity typed characters, for example: type 6 characters, while `ping` is working, then press backspace 6 times  `~/Documents/test_dir$` transforming to `~/Documents/tes`.

Answer (score 5):

Bash *did* get your input from its standard input (stdin), which is the terminal.

A terminal can be in one of two [modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Modes): *raw* or *cooked* (also known as “character mode” and “line mode”, the terms “raw” and “cooked” are mostly used in the Unix world) (the word “cooked” was introduced as a pun to make an opposite to “raw”). In raw mode, the terminal transmits input immediately to the application. In cooked mode, the terminal reads a full line and provides a (very primitive) line edition mechanism, and only transmits the data to the application when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Terminals start in cooked mode. Applications that want more control over input, such as bash, set the terminal in raw mode while they're waiting for the user to type a command.

Comment: So in my example what happened is that when `ping` terminates and `bash` gains back control, `bash` set the terminal to raw mode, which causes the the tty device line buffer (which contains the string *"I typed this while ping was running"* to be flushed to `bash`, and `bash` will display it on the terminal window?

Comment: Also, I don't think that `bash` sets itself completely to raw mode, but rather it just changes some `termios` settings like disabling the tty device line buffering and the tty device echoing

Comment: @paul Yes, I simplified a bit in my answer. “Raw mode” is one specific terminal setting, there are other settings, which you can set through the `stty` command. Raw/cooked is one setting, another is echo (either the terminal echoes what you typed to the screen immediately, or it doesn't and it's up to the application to echo stuff if it wants). Raw usually goes with noecho and cooked with echo but applications are free to pick cooked/noecho or raw/echo if they want.

Comment: Is my first comment correct?

Comment: @paul Yes. While ping runs, the terminal has echo on, and nothing is reading input. Then bash runs, displays a prompt and reads input, and at that point it receives the pre-typed input. Bash handles its own echo so it displays those characters again. By the way, you can check the current terminal modes from another terminal with `stty </dev/pts/…` — that'll let you know what the terminal modes are at a shell prompt (if you run `stty` from that terminal, the shell changes modes before running your command).

Comment: Unclear, how terminal separates the `ping` input from the keyboard input. The `ping` command writes to the terminal, at the same time user presses keys on the keyboard, therefore terminal gets one garbled input, doesn't it?

Comment: @MiniMax ping does not read any input from the terminal. ping writes some output to the terminal. If you type something, it is echoed by the terminal, so this is a second source of output to the terminal. What you type and what ping outputs do get mixed.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, i am understand it. What I am not understanding is this: how in the end we are getting all typed characters - "I typed this while ping was running". How terminal have could extract this string from mixed ping/keyboard input? All it has, is mixed input from two source, which are writing simultaneously. Or exist something else?

Comment: @MiniMax There is no input from ping. Ping writes to the terminal device, that's output, and the terminal displays the output. The terminal device generates input from keyboard events.

Comment: I was thought, that terminal also have own input and output conception. If program writes to terminal, it is go to terminal input. And if program reads from terminal, it is go from terminal output. Wrong? :) Because in old, hardware terminals were two states - send and receive. Input and output. I should read more about it.

Comment: @MiniMax Think of a terminal device as a pair of pipes. Each pipe carries data in one direction: either from the hardware/emulator to the application (this is called input) or from the application to the hardware/emulator (this is called output). The data from ping goes into the output pipe. It doesn't get mixed with what the user types, that goes through the input pipe and in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the terminal buffers every line of text received through the keyboard, such that any program which has a file descriptor (i.e. fd0) attached to the terminals device file - won't see any text from the line until the terminal "sends" it - which happens when you press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
<sub>(How the line editors of shells get around this - I'm not sure, but they definitely get at the text before you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)</sub>

Also when a shell launches a child process (in this case `ping`) it goes into in a suspended/`wait`ing state as the child process runs, so even if the terminal wasn't withholding text from it, the shell would ignore it, assuming it was intended for the child process.

So the text you see appearing on the screen, is because the *terminal* is displaying it, but there is no program capturing it and doing anything with it, until the child exits - and the shell "wakes up' - then the text is sent to the shells line editor. Although I don't think all terminals necessarily do that.

Comment: Interactive editors typically switch the terminal driver to "raw" mode. The line-at-a-time behavior you describe is often referred to as "cooked" mode.

Comment: @tripleee thanks that explains how shells can get the individual chars