# How to automate a keystroke to a cli terminal appilcation like ranger?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, stdin, ncurses

I'd like to send a keystroke to ranger, when I have ranger running and have gotten it's PID with:

Output of `ps aux | grep '[/]usr/bin/python -O /usr/bin/ranger'`:

```
chris     5054  3.1  0.1 116248 27828 pts/0    S+   16:57   0:00 /usr/bin/python -O /usr/bin/ranger
```

Following from https://serverfault.com/a/178470/135542, if I send the value `j` to it's STDIN with:
`echo "j" > /proc/5440/fd/0` I just seem to get `j` mixed in the output (after I ran the command a few times):

[image]

However when I press `j` on my keyboard, it reacts correctly.

Comment: But the `/proc/5440/fd/1` is not the `stdin`, it is the `stdout`. The file descriptor of the `stdin` is 0 or `/proc/5440/fd/0`.

Comment: Sorry I copied that wrongly - to confirm this happens with `/proc/5440/fd/0`.

Comment: These two questions can be helpful: 1) [Why i can't send escape sequences from keyboard, but can do it from another tty?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369845/109397) 2) [How does bash retrieves what was written on the terminal (without Enter being pressed)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366340/109397)

Answer (score 1):

This is because, the

```
echo "j" > /proc/5440/fd/0
```

in fact, is something like this (the `pts` number can be differ in your case):

```
echo "j" > /dev/pts/2
```

**Explanation:**

I doesn't have `ranger`, so I were running `vim` - the no difference here, mechanism the same. Then, I found out the `vim`'s PID - `6466` and looked into the `/proc/6466/fd` directory:

```
$ ls -l /proc/6466/fd
lrwx------ 1 minimax minimax 64 Nov 20 01:20 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 minimax minimax 64 Nov 20 01:20 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 minimax minimax 64 Nov 20 01:20 2 -> /dev/pts/2
```

All file descriptors of the `vim`'s process are symbolic links to the current terminal. So, the `echo "j" > /proc/5440/fd/0` converts to the `echo "j" > /dev/pts/2`, which means literally: "Redirect the output of the `echo` command to the terminal file `/dev/pts/2`". Not to the stdin of the `vim`'s process.

As far as I know, the terminal can get input only from keyboard and there is no way passing input to it somehow else. So, you need search for another method, to passing commands to the working process.

Also, keep in mind, that the `echo` adds the newline to its output, that is causing printing `j` by stairs, in your case. If change it to the `echo -n j`, the output will be `jjj` - without newlines.